# Disable downvoting for users with reputation less than 50

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, new-users

I am new to this site and try to visit it daily. Most of the time, new users get too many downvotes. Some due to not editing their questions properly and some due to asking very basic questions.

Many times in college I was not comfortable with asking my teacher questions. So I never asked. That affected me very badly.

Now if a new user visits our site and asks something very basic we start downvoting. Go and read it at net, google it, see questions asked before of this type.

Now the user is a newbie and at least they tried to ask something. So we should try to encourage the user so next time they can ask more questions and over time they can start getting clear on things.

But by downvoting new users we just discourage them to not ask questions over here.

We should not allow downvoting on users with less than 50 reputation. Because after getting 50 reputation they at least come to know about our site and the standards of asking questions.

Comment: users under 50 reps NEED the downvotes to learn. I don't see why we would refrain from downvoting bad questions/answers "not to hurt the user". If we implement your suggestion we will end up with crappy questions no one can downvote. There are a TON of users with 1 rep that NEVER come back. These users will not be downvotable? this will just turn SO in a scrapyard.

Comment: Btw don't take the downvotes here personally. Downvoting is different on meta :), people downvote here based on opinion more than if the question is bad

Comment: If you did this, users asking crap questions would just be downvoted into oblivion once they reached 50 rep.

Comment: @Julldar [More specifically](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta): "On posts tagged feature-request, voting indicates agreement or disagreement with the proposed change rather than just the quality or usefulness of the post itself."

Comment: `we should try to encourage him/her, so next time he/she can ask more questions` no, we don't want them to ask more questions if they are asking *bad questions*. One of the *points* of downvotes is to discourage this, it's not a side effect

Comment: Hmm. At last i started learning things from this forum :) I respect your views but that was my view and you people just changed my view by your reasonable comments.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, ah, but if you downvote like mad once they hit 50, they will drop under 50 with the first vote, thus protecting them.

Comment: @Mr37037 Also: Stack Overflow is _not_ a forum; It is a Question and Answer site.

Comment: This line of thought should be discouraged, so have my downvote. Seriously now, don't suggest a way to protect newbies from downvotes if you can't suggest an alternative to teach them how to ask.

Comment: The system already prevents rep from going negative (even though there are some posts for which I wish it would).  I don't see any reason why _50_ should be the new _1_.

Comment: @eddie_cat I agree whole-heartedly - I recently asked for a feature request that downvoters should automatically be requested to add a comment for new users, but it was downvoted in Meta - hehe.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

First off, votes are extremely important information about the quality of a post.  That feedback is valuable not only for just the post author, but every single other reader of that post.  It's important for other people to be able to recognize whether a post is of high or low quality.  If people are unable to indicate that a post is of low quality just because the user is new, then that is a failure of the voting system to accomplish it's primary goal.

If the user is getting upvotes for posting low quality content that we don't want on the site then they *aren't* learning how to use the site properly.  They aren't even learning when they're doing something wrong, so they won't even *attempt* to improve.  Then all of a sudden they'll just hit a brick wall where all of a sudden the exact same quality of post go from getting upvotes to getting downvotes.  This isn't fixing the problem in any way, it's just pushing it back a tiny bit.

Comment: Understood Sir :) btw sometimes I used to took this type of comments personally . But today I realized these are for your own betterment. You cant bear them you cant progress.

Comment: @Mr37037, I wish I could upvote your comment 10x or give a bounty to it, should be on the [help] :)

Comment: Votes are also an integral part of the question quality account blocks and the question-asking rate limiters.

Comment: What is the logic behind saying that a new user's downvote is not valid? Anyone can say if something needs to be downvoted. If you worship votes so much then allow everyone to vote!

Comment: @gk_2000 The bar is fairly low, you can get to the point of being able to downvote posts within your first day using a site. As with pretty much everything gated by reputation, the purpose is to ensure people are familiar enough with the relevant systems to ensure they know how to use them properly, as well as to mitigate abuse by potential bad actors creating new accounts for the express purposes of malicious behaviors.

Answer (score 22):

> Don't handicap your children by making their lives easy -- [Robert Heinlein](http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/quotes/r/robertahe106973.html)

When you make it so that if they have less than some amount of rep, you are hiding them from the 'real' world.  When they get that 51 rep, suddenly they will be faced with a different reality.

There is not tutorial mode for Stack Exchange (or the real world).  By trying to hide users from it, they will learn bad habits without the associated negative reinforcement and *then*, when they get access to the 'real world' of the site, they will suddenly find themselves slapped in the face as the training wheels come off.

Furthermore, it is those negative votes that help feed a lot of other systems.  Roomba deleting crappy closed questions? Thats from down votes.  Roomba deleting crappy abandoned questions?  Downvotes can help there too.  Question bans (or rate limits)?  Yep, down votes.

Downvotes are rare enough as it is on crap.  Sure, some things get hit quite hard when they are noticeably bad, but if you go look at all those questions that have one up vote, you've gotta wonder why they even got that.