# A question's score should not be allowed to drop below 0

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, questions, downvotes

If a user did research, read documentation, followed instructions, and looked up similar questions that had been upvoted, the question can be closed or marked as off-topic, but should not be downvoted below zero. It demoralises the user and prevents him or her from using Stack Overflow. What do you think about the idea that only 100k moderators can downvote a question to a score below 0?

Comment: Bad suggestion; there are very few of those, and there'd be no way to control the flow of bad content.  If a user is demoralized.. well, I feel like that's their problem.  I mean, they shouldn't be taking it personal, but as a sign the question needs to be improved.  But that's in an ideal world.. Either way, this is not the answer.

Comment: Comments may be the wrong place for this, but here is a [similar question which managed to fly under the radar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18411517/cannot-access-paypal-developers-account-cannot-import-test-accounts?rq=1), I've voted to close as is appropriate.

Comment: Actually now I feel bad for the other question I referred to. The poor guy has barely enough points left to ask another question. Now my karma is downvoted too :)

Comment: It seems that your assumptions are wrong. You're basically saying that we shouldn't down-vote you because PayPal sent you here? I don't know, but if that is all you can argument with, than you did obviously misinterpret the research part, because you missed to research the environment. If I asked a question about how to best beat a kid on parenting.SE, I couldn't expect to stay positive either. Why? Because it's totally misplaced and off-topic. On christianity.SE however... (just kidding)

Comment: Excuse me I had 3 good arguments, 1) It was about paypal sandbox 2) There was a +1 similar question 3) I was send from the Paypal developer page.

Comment: @GertCuykens They aren't good arguments, though.  1) This isn't support for paypal's website, 2) Two wrongs don't make a right, 3) Unless their support page is unclear, that's for support with their code APIs, aka, ... programming.  Anything else is out of our jurisdiction.

Comment: I am not arguing the off topic decision I am arguing down voting is a bad way to indicate it. Especially if there is no way to improve the question to make it better. Query a list of all offtopic questions and see if they all represent the mercury freezing point. It does not add any value to it. Marking it offtopic does categorize it correctly but downvoting simply turns it into a popularity contest.

Comment: @GertCuykens Closing isn't the answer to everything.  Some questions can be improved, others cannot.  The votes are an indication of quality.  Without them, the flow of bad quality will quickly rise and engulf the site.  This site is liked for the quality of content, for the help it offers.  If users are suddenly unable to downvote, because of the nigh-unreachable 100k requirement, the bad will outnumber the good, and poof, you have yahoo answers.

Comment: If bad questions are zero and good question get upvoted more then everybody is happy and you eliminate the targeting of a individual. A total score of let say -2 should be used in cases where the user is trying to create havoc on the site. Now you could not even distinguish my off topic question form a toilet paper commercial.

Comment: There is no targeting of an individual; it may seem that way, but it's not, especially when such an action is a suspend-able offense.  Content is judged, not the poster.

Comment: Can you imagine when your child would come home from school with a -8 on his paper just because he asked why he got a zero :) I know its not about the individual but indirectly you are targeting the person.

Comment: @GertCuykens If the child refused to follow the rules, didn't do their research, and expected everyone else to do their work for them.. then yes, I could imagine that.  However, that's neither here nor there; what you have above is a bad idea; if questions don't get downvoted, then there is no quality control.  And handing that privilege to 100k users?  I think it's pretty safe to say that's never going to happen, it would ruin the quality of the site.

Comment: In this case the kid answer was the same as the one who got +1. And his private teacher told him to ask the other teacher for advice.

Comment: @GertCuykens I admit, I have a lot of patience, but I don't have infinite patience.  As has already been said to you, two wrongs don't make a right.  The active userbase on this site is not big enough to police all 8 ***million*** questions.  Your example doesn't fly because the other question you pointed out, once it was brought to attention, was downvoted and closed, as it should be.  Stuff does slip through our fingers; when it does, the best thing to do is point it out, not use it as an excuse to post the same thing.

Comment: true but this topic only suggest there is a better solution then downvoting, that's all I am saying. Maybe 100k is not the right one as your arguments suggest, but for me downvoting is also not the best indication. Actually the more my questions gets downvoted the more I can refer to other questions to make my point :)

Comment: @GertCuykens The existence of other questions is not a point; it is an example of what I have repeated a few times now.  There are not enough of us.  They are not an excuse to post similar content; if you spot content that violates the policies of this site, as defined in no uncertain terms in [the help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then report it.  Up-voted content does not automatically make it acceptable.  It just means someone agreed with them, and up-voting is achieved only at 15 rep, compared to the 125 required for down-voting.

Comment: And I appreciate the effort of all of you but let me put in other words then, there are too many questions for downvoting to work like it should. It is as much effort to do +1 then to do -1

Comment: @GertCuykens I disagree; it's working fine.  Otherwise, we'd just be another yahoo answers.  The review queues, while long, are not impossible to conquer.

Comment: In a way downvoting below zero and closing are strongly correlated. So yeah, autoclose all questions with negative scores. :) Just kidding.

Comment: The duplicate is a totally different question. Voting to reopen.

Comment: @user000001: it is the underlying reason for the feature request. The problem here is a failure to understand Stack Overflow voting, and the request will be denied on those grounds. There is no point in reopening this.

Comment: @user000001 http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194476/someone-flagged-my-question-as-already-answered-but-its-not

Comment: @GertCuykens The edits you've made to your question are bringing up a **different topic** from what your original topic was. Please post a new question if you want to discuss that topic. Modifying an old question that was already answered in order to broach a different topic is not okay.

Comment: Ok fair enough I will do that.

Comment: @GertCuykens without commenting on the rest, I agree with you it's extremely deceptive for PayPal to send users here and pretend it's "their forum" or that they operate it. Many other people object to the confusion: [Is Stack Overflow the official PayPal support site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173138/is-stack-overflow-the-official-paypal-support-site) and even a github issue(!) [Will anybody from Paypal ever bother to answer questions on Stackoverflow?](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-node-SDK/issues/186)

Answer (score 21):

I down-vote questions if :

1. It is a home-work dump.
2. The question makes absolutely no sense.
3. The OP is being rude or arrogant.
4. It is a general / popular question which can be *easily* solved by googling (lack of searching effort)

90% of people on SO down-vote because the question is of low quality. Period. 
You are making us *spend* our time on your question while someone else is waiting for an answer to a legitimate/ good question. This isn't fair. A poor question in which the OP has shown *some effort* is also fine. But *laziness* is a strict no-no. Down-voting is like a warning to the OP - *Do your home-work before you ask*.

> *It demoralises the user and prevents him or her from using Stack Overflow*

Well, *not-down-voting* such questions encourages them into asking more poor questions. Which one is better?. AFAIK, we always give a reason for down-voting / closing and redirect the OP to the right place. Examples : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26271366/user-defined-functions-vs-built-in-function-in-java-five-relevant-differences-ov) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26270989/how-can-i-learn-javafx-8).

> *What do you think about the idea that only 100k moderators can downvote a question to a score below 0?*

Not a good idea (I don't think the moderators would disagree :P). A person with a rep of 10 can be way smarter than a person with 100k rep. Your approach would lead to more poor quality questions and heavy load on moderators.

PS: 100K moderators?. *Rep* and *moderation* are 2 different things on SO :P. I wouldn't call people with high reputation as *moderators* (although they have more *privileges*)

Comment: -1, You shouldn't down-vote for arrogance of the OP. Judge the Question/Answer, not the OP. (No, I am not judging you, but the answer you wrote, and I disagree on it ;) )

Comment: @Theolodis Definitely a good thing to point out, re judging the question vs the person. That said; often, I think people displaying such an attitude actually have a 'bad' question to begin with (the attitude coming when people call them on it.) I agree with this answer, but perhaps that item could use some nuance. (and of course, it's perfectly valid to down vote this answer on that point, if you wish!)

Comment: And then to this answer; just a couple other nuances: There is a reason displayed for putting on-hold, but commenting for down votes is manual, and not required. I find it happens more on questions that just need some help, as opposed to *really bad* ones. Perhaps some think that the asker put in so little effort, they don't feel taking the time to comment would be productive. Also: Tiny nuance; we sometimes use the word "moderation" in reference to what people do with rep-based abilities, although you are right that they are not technically "moderators". Still gave +1 here, though!

Comment: ["Don't handicap your children by making their lives easy..."](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272269/839601)

Comment: @Theolodis - I don't mind your down vote :P. **Judge the Question/Answer** I will down-vote rude / arrogant people. Why?? because he / she will spoil the mood and demotivate us.

Comment: @AndrewBarber - I agree. Yes, I've seen cases where questions are down-voted because people think see *lack of effort*.

Comment: @TheLostMind And given that that's one of the reasons specified *right in the downvote tooltip* clearly that's an intended purpose.