# Do we need editors for newcomers to improve the question asked by him, till he gets an idea about how to ask the question?

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request

Do we need editors for newcomers, because its often found that newcomers make a lot of mistake while asking questions and the downvoting against their questions is so fast that he cannot rise up again and need to create another login id to get the help from the website.

Another solution would be that first 2 questions should not be downvoted they should be just edited to teach the newcomers about how to ask the questions....

Comment: elders should bear the mistakes of minors and teach them with love.

Comment: This is not kindergarten. There is a help-center full of stuff, I don't see how users that didn't care in the first place will pick up advice later on. We get 1000 new questions everyday, if some of them are below our quality level new people assume it is ok to post low quality stuff.

Comment: First Posts *are* part of a review queue already. Also, there is no reason to create a new login ID. Users have the power to remove their own questions, edit them, or resubmit.

Comment: There already are "editors for newcomers". That's the "First Posts" queue.

Comment: OK, this sounds like a winner.  I'm voting YOU to be on the screening and editing panel.  I hope you have a LOT of free time.

Comment: I very strongly oppose limiting downvotes in any manner that's not equally applied to upvotes.  By preventing downvotes on user's first two questions, you're just delaying their real introduction to SO.  And would actually probably lead to even more disgruntlement, as they'd ask two questions, not get any downvotes, and figure their questions are acceptable.  They ask yet another in the same manner, and it gets downvoted to hell.  Now we have a confused user wondering why their new question got such a brutal reception, when their first ones were alright.

Comment: For the first time nobody is perfect.

Comment: It's not about perfection.  Never has been.  It's about enforcing quality standards.  Users are just the vehicles for content.  Content is judged, not the user.

Comment: @Dipali: They are not here before 13

Comment: I found this question really helpful then I saw the down vote, lol.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, we, as a community, don't scale well enough to support that.

We already have review queues that are handled by community members:

- First Posts
- Low Quality Posts
- Close Votes ([could use more users that handle those](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers)).

Beyond that there are quality filters in place as well as [limiting the number of questions new users can ask over a given time-period](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271542/why-wont-the-system-allow-me-to-ask-questions-for-several-days). And the help-center is full of good material as is Meta and [Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/). What you're looking for might be in the [pipeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236537/lets-have-an-explicit-triage-system-for-questions-from-new-users)

This site is for professionals and enthusiasts. We have to expect them to read and understand what is already there. If not, then maybe SO is not yet the place for them.

Comment: FWIW, SE team is considering something beyond what's there now: **[Let's have an explicit triage system for questions from new users](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/236537/165773)**

Comment: @gnat The idea of a triage system is mostly about more effectively feeding the review queues; trying to figure out more effectively which posts belong in a queue, which queue they belong in, how they should be priorities within those queues, etc.  I wouldn't expect how users interact with these queues to change *all* that much, if that system is actually put in place.

Comment: @Servy this is about improving review process, and if you take into account that there are [over 100,000 users](http://stackoverflow.com/users?page=3000&tab=reputation&filter=all "over 3,000 pages by 36 users each") eligible to do FP review, making it more efficient and convenient for them can potentially make tremendous headroom to scale the "inception" of new users

Answer (score 3):

Let's take your second proposed solution at face value.  Here's what I see happening:

- New user asks a question.  In the spirit of the majority of new users, they didn't read the How To Ask, and ignored all the lovely advice that gets put in front of them when first asking a question.  So their first question is an *outstandingly* bad question, and probably runs afoul of one of the off-topic reasons.
- Their question can't be downvoted, because new user.  It might even get some upvotes.  If it's off-topic, all that can be done is closure.
- User comes to Meta, because they're confused.  Their question got closed, but it was upvoted.  They don't know what they did wrong, never mind whatever comments or the close reason says.
- They get advice on how to fix their question, which they promptly ignore, because it's a positively scored question.  It doesn't actually get reopened, because they ignored what needs to be fixed.  The roomba doesn't automatically delete it, because it's positively scored.
- Same thing happens with second question.  Still bad, still gets closed.  Maybe even a duplicate of their first question, because it got closed the first time.
- New user asks third question, and promptly gets downvoted into oblivion, because they haven't actually learned anything from what they were told on the first two questions.
- Now the new user is very upset, because they didn't get any downvotes on their first couple of questions, and that same level of quality is in their new question.  Two questions of theirs have no downvotes, and maybe even some upvotes.  But the new question is very heavily downvoted.  They don't understand why that happened.

---

All this proposal does is prevent enforcement of Stack Overflow's quality standards until new users pass an arbitrary minimum question threshold.  What this will do is effectively split SO into two camps: new users that haven't passed the threshold, which we'll call "Cuddly SO", and users that have passed the threshold, called, "Real SO".

Cuddly SO has the primary quality standard disabled.  Without downvotes, the only method any 3K user has to send a signal of a problematic question is to close it.  Closing a question is meant to be a temporary state most of the time, either to prevent answers until the question can be cleaned up properly, or on its way to deletion.  Upvotes dull both of these messages, as obviously *somebody* thinks the question is acceptable.  What is missing is the signal that *doesn't* think the question is acceptable.  That signal is actively disabled.

This leads to a rather rude awakening as soon as the user hits Real SO.  What used to be an "acceptable" level of effort turned out to not actually be that acceptable.  What we'll get is a very confused user, pointing at their initial questions.  They're upvoted, or, at worst, neutral.  Their new question is the same as their previous ones, but now it's very heavily downvoted.  What's going on?

We send an inconsistent message with this proposal.  We're saying that the new user's experience with Stack Overflow is more important than the level of quality of their content.  Once the user passes into Real SO, the divide between Cuddly SO and Real SO is going to hit them in the face, because new users *aren't* more important than content quality.  It will lead to a new user being even *more* disgruntled, because the message changes at some arbitrary threshold.

Not to mention, but the question ban relies on downvotes as part of the algorithm to detect if questions are actually acceptable.  With this proposal, we're actually allowing them to post more questions before the slowdown or outright ban kicks in.  I can also see this being abused.  Ask two questions.  Delete account, create new account.  Ask two more questions, repeat.  No downvotes, ever!

At the end of the day, the StackExchange network isn't about users.  Never has been.  It's been about their *content*.  That, above all else, is what matters.

Comment: content for whom ?

Comment: ["Don't handicap your children by making their lives easy..."](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272269/839601)