# No soup for you - you ask broad questions

Tags: discussion

Most of my broad questions come when I know very little of the subject matter, and am just beginning to explore.

I have a feeling that someone that asks really broad questions is probably helped by general direction (web sites, resources, books, etc).  I understand that this can get into opinionated land, and subjective answers.

I feel that as the best place to find answers, we may do well to encourage people with 6 points, and a broad question, to learn something.  I don't see much of a point in down-voting them and closing their question as too broad.

My one suggestion is that we leave the comments section open so that anyone that wants to help may post links to resources.

How do we help people that ask really broad questions? They just want to learn.

Comment: http://www.google.com/

Comment: ["Don't handicap your children by making their lives easy..."](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272269/839601)

Comment: @Shqiptar_Programmer google can't always solve your problems. StackOverflow is the one place left to turn before spending days digging through manuals and calling up friends from college.

Comment: If a question is too broad, then by definition it's a giant topic and there is almost certainly literature about it on Google. I don't see a problem with pointing them to that literature in comments.

Comment: Related on Meta.SE: [How can a noob ask questions about "how to start with this cool stuff"?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/181993) [How to ask a "where to start" question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/100036) and especially [Are "point me in the right direction" questions acceptable?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226103)

Answer (score 19):

> How do we help people that ask really broad questions?

We don't.  They're not in scope in this site.  If you have very broad questions then you should be going to other places to get answers, not SE.  (This could be other sites, books, schools, etc.)

SE can't be everything to everyone.  It has picked certain things that are in scope, and it does those few things very well.  Being able to teach a brand new user a large amount of information about a whole topic simply isn't one of those things that this site decided to be.

Comment: job security right?

Comment: @r3wt No...considering there are tons and tons of resources all over the place that *are* designed to do this, and do it very well.  It's not like there's no place to go to find tutorials on a topic, it's just that SE isn't that place.

Comment: tutorials are misleading, thats the problem. how do you expect a more educated and competent tech sector if you want to argue semantics, instead of you know, actually helping people by giving sage advice on best practices?

Comment: @r3wt If all tutorials are terrible, then why do you want SE to start hosting tutorials?  They'd be terrible, according to you.  Or are you saying that all tutorials everywhere *except SE* are terrible?

Comment: because it would give experts a chance to form a consensus on best practices.

Comment: @r3wt If you want to see a site where experts can go to create a consensus on best practices in their tutorial then go create a site where experts can go to collaborate on tutorials.  You certainly won't be alone in that sector, but if you think you will be, have at it.

Comment: "it's not a democracy" isn't a valid rebuttal.

Comment: @r3wt So you're saying that you have the right to force SE to do something that it doesn't want to do?  You feel that SE is obligated to create tutorials for you just because you want them to?

Comment: I'm saying we should have the right to come to a consensus on the matter. I'm sure i'm not the only one who would be interested in it.

Comment: @r3wt You do.  If you want to see a site that functions similar to SE, but is designed around creating tutorials, then *go create such a site*.  If SE doesn't want to create one, you as a user of that site do not have the right to force them to do what you want.  You have the ability to vote with your feet, but that's all.  There are an infinite number of things that people are interested in; that doesn't mean SE needs to do all of them.  I'm interested in having my car washed, and I imagine lots of other SE users are too; should SE now enter the car wash industry?

Comment: That argument is weak and you know it. programming tutorials and getting carwashes aren't even in the same hemisphere in terms of their relationship to this website.

Comment: @r3wt And yet you have and equal ability to force SE to move into either of those sectors, and SE has an equal ability to choose to move into either of those sectors if it wants to.  SE is not obligated to start creating tutorials just because you want them to, no matter how close or far the topic is to what SE's current goals are.

Comment: I didn't say that. I merely posed it as an open ended question to anyone from SO who might possibly read this.  you were being dismissive, and i disagreed with you. now you're just using straw-man to dissuade me from the continuance of my argument.

Comment: Expert stick around SE *because* they have a say in how the site is run and have input into what is and isn't on-topic.  SE would probably post *fantastic* tutorials.  At first.  The site would be overrun with them, and become unmanageable, and those same experts would leave.  Many of the reasons newcomers want SE to support something is because of the expertise it attracts.  Expertise that evaporates when they are inundated with things that don't interest them.  And then the site dies.