# Is answering a dupe acceptable as to not "scare away" new users?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, help-vampire

Yesterday [this question (deleted, 10K only)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28102531/why-use-readonly-for-repository?noredirect=1#comment44580743_28102531) was posted. I voted to close as duplicate but two high rep users answered the question (and didn't vote to close). To sum up the comments, I asked why we were answering the question and I was told that it was to not "frighten them from using SO again".

Is this acceptable? I feel as though this just leads to help vampires and overall it's just a way for anyone to cheese the point system.

Comment: I personally think dupes are perceived to be a negative thing. In my mind, they're not. The answer already exists, the OP should have been able to find it, but was unable to.

Comment: Unfortunately, people can, and do, answer whatever they feel like; heck, I saw a 255K+ member answer a blatantly off-topic question yesterday and get three upvotes.  If I'm feeling really grumpy against behavior like this, I'll just favorite the question and go back and delete it later.  The answerers will lose some reputation since their answers will get deleted with the question, and the OP will possibly gain some reputation back from the inevitable downvotes the question received. There's nothing wrong with closing a question if it's off-topic; answering it just creates more clutter.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables they're ["behaving like hyenas just to get some extra points..."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244261/what-is-people-helped-and-why-does-it-exist-at-all#comment798506_244290)

Comment: @gnat - man, you have a link for *everything* :D

Comment: There is a blog or somesuch by one of the J's about dupe posts and answers being ok.  Not sure how dated it is.

Comment: BTW, I disagree with the notion that dupe links "scare away" new programmers.  Very often you can tell from the timestamps of comments that they did not even look at the link, or skimmed it at best.  Posters tend to want a personalized answer lovingly hand crafted to their localized problem and are unable/unwilling to extract salient details from the dupe link if it is the least bit different.

Comment: @Plutonix [Dr. Strangedupe: Or, How I Learned to Stop Worrying And Love Duplication](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/) ("have a link for _everything_":)

Comment: SO users that get up to speed usually are still inclusionary.  That automatically takes care of itself.  Lets direct ire at the OP here, the ultimate enabler for this behavior.  All he had to do was google "why use readonly" to get the answer he needed.  Not sure how this happened, somewhere between drastically inept and plain lazy perhaps.  Do we really want users like this to contribute?  A month-long question ban seems appropriate to me.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No, this is not an acceptable reason.

It looks like the target dupe has plenty of well-received answers that I would assume (without being an expert there) covers the accepted answer in your link.

If none of those answers (I doubt it in this situation) address the specific problem of the OP then sure it is fine but not to spoon feed new users. That's not meant to sound mean but we do enough of that.

We were all new at one point. Those who want to contribute to, learn from, and be a part of the site will not let a dupe closing scare them away. Rather, they will be thankful for the help in pointing out the already stellar answers previously given.

**off-topic** that question sounds pretty broad to me.

Comment: ["Don't handicap your children by making their lives easy..."](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272269/839601)

Answer (score 8):

One can close as a duplicate *and* still be helpful and welcoming to a brand new OP.

When faced with this situation, instead of diving straight into the duplicate closure, I'll instead first locate the duplicate, and in particular a specific answer on the dupe and grab its `share` link.

Then I manually leave a comment to the effect of:

> There's an answer [over here] which seems like it would suit your needs quite well.  This is a question that comes up frequently around here.

Then, I close as a duplicate. Other closevoters see the close count, and eventually when the question is closed, the normal duplicate banner goes to the top.

The OP gets a warm and welcoming comment instead of the robotic

> possible duplicate of .....

...and the question is closed.

[Here is a recent real-world example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28079837/how-do-i-echo-a-different-statement-when-different-checkboxes-are-selected-with#comment44538459_28079837) in which I could point the OP at the target dupe, suggest how their code would be adapted to the existing answer, and then close it with my dupehammer. (visible as long as no one flags & removes the referenced comment)

So to address the question asked here - *is it okay to answer?* No. There are alternatives. Other less experienced users will probably answer before the closure is complete unless you have a dupehammer, but experienced users who know the landscape and keep a mental catalog of existing answers can navigate this scenario without scaring off new users.

Comment: That extra-warmth might be a good idea, if it's a question by a new user, and he seems to have taken his time to ask properly. Of course, doing that repeatedly just wears one out. And also, unless you add some more content to that link, it should be removed as obsolete / too chatty really fast. Best by yourself, to spare the mods avoidable extra-work.

Comment: @Deduplicator It may - If it were me, I would definitely not flag a comment like that as too chatty.  Most of the time, I close in tags where I have a dupehammer though, so it doesn't matter as much if the comment is lost as long as the OP is still engaged with the question. If the OP asks and leaves as new users do, then I'd have to hope nobody flags that comment.

Comment: Even after the user added another comment, or was otherwise active *clearly after that*?

Comment: @Deduplicator For flagging? I don't usually flag comments chatty or obsolete until it appears the question has settled - been closed or has an accepted answer.  Offensive or not constructive are different though. So yes, maybe I'd flag it if closure was complete.