# Summer time - is it still acceptable to close as duplicate?

Tags: discussion

It's summer time in some places... Is guidance the same as usual to close items as duplicate (like [Is answering a dupe acceptable as to not "scare away" new users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284360/is-answering-a-dupe-acceptable-as-to-not-scare-away-new-users)) or there is new "summer of love" where it is better to post similar answers over closing as duplicates?

Since there is absolutely no initiatives for people to prefer "close as duplicates" were created for long time maybe it is time to revise the policy and flat out allow/embrace duplicates?

---

Question prompted this - [Algorithm to create area filled points on Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31061122/algorithm-to-create-area-filled-points-on-map) which got 2 answers essentially saying "duplicate of this question" by established users.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I'm glad I'm on the same page about duplicates as accepted answer/most votes.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's always best to close as a duplicate.

We don't want answers to the same question littered all over the site requiring that future visitors have to hunt around for the information they need.

If users - especially established users - are posting answers that are essentially links to other questions then they need to be reminded of how Stack Overflow operates.

Comment: Thanks for guidance and nice comments on the original SO question.