# Are we too preoccupied with easy questions?

Tags: discussion, answers, asking-questions, closed-questions

I don't follow many tags so I can't speak for the general population, but something has been really confusing me, and honestly starting to bother me.

The main concern is when users ask bad question. I say bad question because not more than 5 minutes later it gets closed.

The problem with that is the rush on answering those question, I mean it's incredible. By the time I click on it and read what the person said, I notice it's a question with little research so I search the internet and other SO posts for possible duplicates. By the time I go back to flag it (once I find the correct post) it has received many answers.

[How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). The first thing it suggests is to "Search and research", well this is an advice to get good answers to your questions I know that, but if the users has clearly done no research, why are we so eager to jump and answer the question? Is it because it's too easy?

To be specific to a post, please keep in mind this isn't the first one today alone, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31076763/behavior-of-max-with-string-parameters) the user has asked a question, instantly the number of views on this has spiked and the answers flooded in. All I did was a single search about the same problem and found many answers to it.

The answers provided explain the problem quite well actually, but why jump so quick to it. This even leads to the [FGITW](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem) problem, which is another story. But why give it so much attention while other questions actually deserve that instead?

My question really is: Are we answering these questions too quickly because they're easy? Are we concerned about getting the approved answer?

Comment: I suppose many users see this kind of behaviour as the only way to gain a meaningful amount of reputation. They're likely not identical with those users who try to keep quality up through closing and editing and such

Comment: @Pekka웃 I saw this action from a 200k+ user as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, high rep does not mean they care about the site's overall quality. So it's completely believable you've seen this from a 200k+ user. They're not in it to help keep the site clean, either they just want more points _or_ they're in that odd class of users that refuses to close questions by new users when instead they can answer it. (I have seen a few people like that.)

Comment: Ah, it's [the bikeshed problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31253/the-bikeshed-problem-and-stack-exchange) again. And yes, some high-rep users do fall for it.

Comment: The most common answer I've seen is, "We're all here to help", without the answerer taking into account the damage they're doing to the site by answering said questions.

Comment: It's also worth noting that for a lot of easy questions writing an answer will actually be faster than trying to find a good duplicate to vote to close.  Much as I hate to admit it, I have, from time to time, answered a question just because I couldn't be bothered to spend the considerably more time it would have taken me to find a duplicate.

Comment: @Servy if it takes a considerable time that could indicate that the OP might have done some himself but couldn't find one. But I'm more referring to the ones that are just plain obvious.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi also,[Stack Overflow technology makes me write bad answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/171172/165773)

Comment: I think yes. I am not endorsing the rant/ragequit here, but relevant food for thought: [Why I No Longer Contribute to StackOverflow](http://michael.richter.name/blogs/why-i-no-longer-contribute-to-stackoverflow).

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables Sometimes the best way to help is not to. I know it sounds oxymoronic but something needs to be done. Some of the link other users are posting are only proving this. SO is a great site and without it I wouldn't have found solution to my problem, so in return I like to contribute back. If this issue dates so far back(5 years+), why ignore it. I don't think anyone expects an easy fix or an overnight solution but will it end?

Comment: Not so sure what's going on lately, today there was a jokester that proposed accepting duplicate Q+A because it's summertime.   Wot?  If there would ever be a vote whether SO should be a forum or a Q+A site, I'm not so sure which wins anymore.  Q+A is hard work and not that much fun, bummer.  Meanwhile, don't let the behavior of a few naughty boys lead you astray.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm not going to rage quit because of it. Like I said before I like to contribute back if possible, and I enjoy helping people when I can. I expect there to be some exploits, it comes with every system out there. I do believe, however, that it can be minimized significantly.

Comment: You have seen nothing yet. The SQL tag is 95% questions about a specific query, schema and data but with almost no information about schema and data. Also asked by someone who has no idea about query optimization and can't really understand sophisticated answers. They want a quick fix. People answer these question immediately and quickly, often with garbage guessing answers. It's like the one-eyed answering for the blind. Questions are almost never closed in the SQL tag, even the most egregious examples of "fails to demonstrate the problem".

Comment: Well Leb, it seems your one of the "caretakers": [Why is Stack Overflow so negative of late?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late#252077). It is sometimes really hard for them. If you like to stay here, you need to get used to that behavior, because it happens a lot.

Comment: @Kendra People can be interested in keeping the site clean *and* in gaining reputation.

Comment: I asked just the same questions in two days after you, lol.  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298073

Comment: It's really unfortunate it has gotten this far without improvement. Especially when you know for a fact that users like Tom said "caretakers" that have been here for a while just have to get used to it, while new users like me see it at such an early stage. Whether my post get flagged for duplicate or AdamSkywalker's it just comes to prove that this matter is persistent and unresolved.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm actually happy my ["summer time"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297804/summer-time-is-it-still-acceptable-to-close-as-duplicate) question got plenty of downvotes, also unfortunately it does not reflect opinions of people who actually post answers to such questions (sometimes link-only to existing answers). It would be nice if SE do something that searching for duplicates would net at least 0 balance compared with current time spent for no rewards + negative comments.

Answer (score 22):

You're essentially asking why people (not always but often) do low-cost things that benefit themselves instead of higher-cost things that benefit other people.  I think you already know the answer to this.

To me the more interesting question is what can be done to improve the situation.  My feeling is that establishing a culture with norms against this behaviour is a good way -- but that it's very hard to maintain this on a large scale, with new people flooding in all the time.  So I'm in favour of *processes that provide direct incentives*.  For example:

- If you answer a question that is later closed as "bad", you get a rep penalty.  (Maybe you "just" lose whatever rep you got from upvotes to your answer; this would have the side benefit of having no impact on people whose motivation for answering questions is not rep.)
- If you decide that a question is "bad", *independently* of other SO users, and the question is eventually closed as a result, you get a rep reward.  Right now I think the only fair way to do this is to limit it to questions that are found to be dupes, since with dupes there's a neat way of objectively testing whether two people's assessment of question quality agrees (I just searched Meta for the post where I described this several years ago -- it had 11 or 12 upvotes as I recall -- and of course it's been <strike>deleted</strike>[moved to Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37466/give-an-incentive-for-finding-duplicate-questions/70855#70855); anyway, if you're interested, it's based on the [ESP game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESP_game) concept of Luis von Ahn), and I can't think of a comparable scheme for accomplishing this with broader measures of question quality (but perhaps someone else can?)

Many would find these too heavy-handed, so I'm sure I'll receive some downvotes.  (I also anticipate a different category of downvotes, the explanation for which will be that I should have posted these suggestions elsewhere, perhaps under a separate question.)  I'd welcome suggestions for improvements or explanations of why these methods would not work (e.g., because they might create some perverse counterincentive that I've overlooked).

I'm actually not a believer in the idea that we need to keep the site "clean" of bad questions: I think it's normal and healthy for bad questions to fall out of sight and out of mind.  But if being "clean" is the goal, then we should look at steps to change towards that -- and wondering aloud why people aren't better people than they currently are never strikes me as the best way to do this.

Comment: Never got any rewards for moderation. Where do I apply?

Comment: Point 1: [Stop the gamers - neutralize rep earned on answers to questions closed within 24 hours](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214426) Point 2: [Reward finding duplicate questions +10 +2 -5](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/90620) (Aside: if you wrote a Meta answer "several years ago", it's likely been moved over to [Meta.SE] during that site's [creation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/212631/), rather than deleted outright; you should try looking there.)

Comment: hope this techniques will be implemented.

Comment: You bring good suggestions on how to improve it, and being downvoted for that is blatantly rude. It's the same as being wrong for having an opinion. My question wasn't mainly aimed at providing suggestions but more to show how quickly I was able to observe these problems with a great site. Individuals who have been here for a while and have seen a broader range of poor questions are able to provide better possibilities to fix them than I could.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: Thanks, I found my post there (as well as another fun post I thought had been deleted!)

Answer (score 15):

I suspect that a lot of people look at easy questions and say "Hey, I can answer that!" and proceed to answer in hopes of getting imaginary internet points.  Their first thought it probably not "This has to have been asked and answered already.  Let me find the dupe hammer."  They are probably more worried about their rep score than the site as a whole. (I say probably only because I can't speak for everyone, that's just my guess.)

"Being helpful" is nice and all.  But what is that old saying about giving a man help and teaching him how to help himself? (Or was it about fish... can't remember.)

Comment: I'm not sure it is always about the rep.  Some people have an idea of helping is giving answers to a specific user because he asked.  I do it sometimes too.  It is hard to not want to try to help someone even though it is better to find the duplicate and just point them to the dup

Comment: `But what is that old saying about giving a man help and teaching him how to help himself? (Or was it about fish... can't remember.)`  You're looking for: `Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime.` ... Ironic you didn't 'research' that :p

Comment: majority of the time it seems answering a dupe anyway still nets positive rep, so of course people are still going to do it.

Comment: I think you're looking for this one:  "Give someone a fish and they'll think you're a bit of weirdo; teach someone how to fish and they'll wonder what fishing has got to do with web design."  [Jeremy Keith]

Comment: "imaginary internet points" -- part of the problem, at least for new users who are going to tend to answer more than they ask, is that these users still need a certain amount of these "imaginary" points to be able to downvote, flag, or close these kinds of questions.

Comment: "Build a man a fire, and he'll be warm for a day. Set a man on fire, and he'll be warm for the rest of his life." —Terry Pratchett, _Jingo_.

Answer (score 6):

So I'm of two minds.

My first mind said:

## YES, we obsess over the easy questions because they're easy!

You can answer them over your morning coffee or during your fifteen minute break.  You get points, they get knowledge, everyone walks away happy.

It's a quick fix, too - you get a chance to help someone out in a jiffy, and you feel like you've done the community a service by helping them out with something you had figured out in your head at the snap of your fingers.

I confess in the early days of my Stack Overflow tenure, I was obsessed with that as well.  To an extent I still am, but I've worked on improving the quality of my answers more than the speed at which I've answered them.  Even if they're easy, there's always a hidden truth to why it has to be that way in the first place.

My second mind said:

## I can't find more complex questions to answer consistently.

I'm pretty much stuck with what I've got; the questions which send *me* on a wild goose chase in the depths of the language spec, which require me to turn my Java compatibility down to 1.3, or require me to think about a sort of problem I hadn't thought would be possible...those are hard to find and few and far between.

It's also due to the volume of questions we get here.  There's something close to 10 million questions on the site already, and that number increases by about 7,000 daily.  There's a lot of questions that don't  rise to the occasion of something that a mid-level software engineer ponders on.  The ones that do may be lost in the noise; they may be the ones that [we're routinely ignoring](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/295713/1079354) as a matter of course.

But the **worst** part is, once you actually *do* find a question you can answer that's more complex than the average homework assignment, *and* you answer it in a way that provides curated references, example code, and at least two other ways to go about solving the problem, **no one pays it any attention.**  The eyeballs are all going to the simpler, quicker, easy-to-rationalize-about problems that we see streaming through the site.

---

It might be the case that the easier questions are quicker to rationalize and agree on, and this is very much true.  It's far easier to find bugs in a trivial snippet of code.  This is why we're drawn to handling the easier questions.

Comment: I could agree with the first one, but the problem with that is that it'll lead to more questions of its sort being asked instead of taking the time for the OP to look it up. Some of the questions I mark duplicate, I'm pretty sure I found a well explained post faster than it took the OP to post it and most definitely faster than waiting for a reply. Secondly, there is no doubt the number of questions increases here, but what if a question gets its own ranking based on difficulty. The vote up is more about if the question is well researched, bounty to get more attention, how about difficulty?

Comment: The difficulty with determining difficulty is that it's subjective and largely dependent on what operations a person is talking about doing.  For instance, a year ago I was getting into IntelliJ plugin development for a week-long hackathon, and found that their documentation was horrendously barren.  I *could* have posted a question here asking on what it was I was attempting to accomplish, but given the scarce amount of resources, I didn't have any confidence that I'd get an answer in a reasonable time frame.

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes the easy questions are also *fun* questions. I've noticed in the python tag that a great many of the easy questions involve little puzzles about lists or strings and can be solved in just a few elegant lines of code. You see in a flash the sort of thing that needs to be done so you fire up the interpreter and get a working solution within a couple of minutes. Nothing deep there -- but why not post an answer that gave you a couple of minutes of enjoyment with the added benefit that it might help the OP?

On edit: as soon as I wrote the above I went back to stack overflow and saw this: [Is there a way to check if a list is a sublist of another list?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31106841/4996248) . How could a Python programmer resist such a thing? (Obviously you can resist answering -- I did, but it is hard to resist thinking about it, if only for a few seconds).

Comment: I agree: answering can be fun.  But that question you link to is a perfect example of the problem: there's *no way* that hasn't be asked before, and indeed it was closed as a duplicate.  Spreading answers out all over the place and repeating work is not beneficial to the site, even if it's beneficial to the individual.

Comment: @davidism well said. In the end you can't get the fun you're looking for if the site doesn't operate like it's supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered many, many times. It happens when you cross "help vampires" with "rep whores"

[Why is Stack Overflow so negative of late?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251758/#252077)

Comment: I believe those threads should be seen as a sign that a problem exists, not as "we know the problem exists, o well deal with it".  [The bikeshed problem and Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31253/the-bikeshed-problem-and-stack-exchange) (5 yrs ago), [Stack Overflow technology makes me write bad answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171172/stack-overflow-technology-makes-me-write-bad-answers) (2 yrs ago), [Why is Stack Overflow so negative of late?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late#252077)(1 yr ago).

Comment: I agree with that as well. That's why the problem needs to be minimized instead of eliminated. Removing the problem completely is impossible and unrealistic to be expected, but implementing a system to minimize it should be more doable. Just like with real life problems (maybe a bit extreme to take SO to that level) you can't get rid of unemployment or crimes but you can find methods to reduce them.

Answer (score -2):

It is not only about internet points. I answer questions because I can. I feel like I did some good by helping some random person on the internet with a real problem. And I guess I like to show off that I know something (happens rarely enough, so it must be treasured). All in all it is good fun.

When I close a question I get none of that. I didn't solve a problem*, I don't get internet points and I could not show off. Also half the time I feel like the community reaction is unhelpful like the typical copy & paste comments like "*This is not an answer. Use comments to ask for clarifications.*" to 1 rep users.

To fix the problem change the reward system. Instead of giving rep to the first person to answer a trivial question give `10 rep + answer_upvotes * 5` rep to the one who finds a duplicate and successfully closes it (just a first idea, needs lots of tweaking).

*closing as duplicate could be seen as solving a problem, but it really doesn't feel like it.

Comment: The intent of Stack Overflow is to be a Q+A site. What use is a Q+A site if there are lots of duplicate questions, with exactly the same answer? A certain amount is unavoidable - for different *enough* questions, not the old heart-cry of "but my variables have different names!". The Help Center instructs to "Please look around to see if your question has been asked before."

Comment: @Jongware I agree. That is why SO should reward closing duplicates instead of rewarding answering them.

Comment: Those are not "copy&paste comments". What you see are comments that are added automatically when people vote on a post in a review queue.

Comment: I like the _idea_ of rewarding dupe closers, but I think it'd be hard to do properly, since we want to encourage people to find the _best_ dupe for a question, not FGITW something vaguely similar so they win the points.

Comment: FWIW, I don't consider dupe questions as being as bad as other close-worthy questions. True, they do often arise due to lack of research, but apart from that, dupe question can be valuable as alternate portals. But that's most effective if only 1 question in a family of dupes has answers. OTOH, sometimes a new question comes along that's technically a dupe, but it presents the problem in a superior manner to the existing dupe target(s). In that situation, it makes sense to me to answer the new, better question & close the _old_ question as a dupe.

Comment: I think far too many questions are being closed as duplicate today. They get closed if they even sound similar to another question. Everything is a Turing Engine, should all questions be closed as duplicate? I would like it if it were much, much harder to close as duplicate, or at least much easier to re-open (e.g. how about the # required to re-open is == to the number that had to vote to close (ignoring badges)?)

Comment: @NetMage We already have that. It takes 5 regular people to close/reopen and 1 gold badge user to close/reopen. Also the people who closed the question cannot close it again after it has been reopened. People are encouraged to show their research and write "This question (link) is related and it says X, but it doesn't cover my case because". I feel like this is the proper way of not getting your question closed as a duplicate because it helps clarifying the question.