# Is it a NoobOverflow or everything is OK?

Tags: discussion, reputation

I noticed that questions on basic topics like class design, work with strings/arrays (most of them are duplicated in some way) usually get tons of attention and several answers in first ten minutes, when some real-life problems (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30833508/how-can-i-obfuscate-all-the-urls-in-my-web-application), random example) sometimes sink and never get an asnwer.

I wonder if there is some way to change this trend, so SO members mostly helped others with real problems rather than tried to get reputation on noob duplicated questions.

Comment: It's called "Bikeshedding" - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parkinson%27s_law_of_triviality

Comment: see also [Why are so many useless questions ranked highly, and vice versa?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287163/839601)

Comment: yes, same question was asked two days ago, I close this one.