# How did this question get so many views?

Tags: discussion, hot-questions

Okay, I admit it. I am at least partly motivated here by a basic annoyance that a question that is so obviously a duplicate has been jumped on by so many users and (IMHO inappropriately) upvoted, along with the answer.

But I think a rant about that, and any sort of call for action, is inappropriate. A couple of people won a lottery somehow, and in the broader view it amounts to just "noise". Nothing really to worry about.

But I am still curious: *how* did they win the lottery? The question [Unexpected behavior of Substring in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32906320) has received over 1500 views since being posted yesterday. Even in the highly active C# tag, this is an incredible amount of traffic in such a short period of time.

I assume that the ridiculously high number of up-votes the question and answers have received is related to this high level of traffic. But where did that traffic come from? How do *I* get that kind of visibility when I ask a question? I don't care about the rep, but the few questions I ask tend to be more esoteric, and I'd sure like the advantage of getting more eyeballs to increase the odds someone would know the answer!

How did that question get so much visibility in such a short period of time?

**EDIT:** to reiterate, I am not asking how this question or its answers got so many upvotes, as in the proposed duplicate link. I take as granted the answer found there, that the upvotes result from a high level of traffic. I'm asking **where that high level of traffic came from**.

(Questions related to the basic nature of the question, but which don't really address my question above, include [Should there be a deterrent for answering obvious duplicate questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252009) and [Are we too preoccupied with easy questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297853))

Comment: If it's getting enough points, it will be listed in the _'hot questions'_ section.

Comment: Oh hey, this question. Why am I *not* surprised that it made it to hot network questions.

Comment: I was one of the views. I clicked on it from hot network questions. I guess the intriguing nature of the title helped motivate that decision. I was curious about what the unexpected behaviour might be.

Comment: "But I think a rant about that, and any sort of call for action, is inappropriate." FYI, on meta, linking to a question is an implicit call to action. So... yeah.

Comment: @MartinSmith That made me think of an alternate universe Stack Overflow in which all titles are phrased like **You won't believe what this .NET method has just done!**

Comment: I'm not sure why that has been duplicated this way around... the answers to the newer question seem to be better and explain the behaviour in multiple different ways.

Comment: All due respect to @gnat et all, I disagree that this is a duplicate, at least of the stated question. The essence of the answers to that other question is "the question got lots of views", and is asking why the question got lots of upvotes. My question is the next step in that chain of analysis: I take as granted the upvotes resulted from the high number of views. My question is not "why the high number of votes", but rather **"why the high number of views"**. This is answered neither by the linked "duplicate" nor _its_ duplicate link.

Comment: @BoltClock: _"linking to a question is an implicit call to action"_ -- point taken. But that is why the (failed?) attempt to clarify that I'm not making a call to action here. I took the action I felt necessary at the post itself (thanks for fixing my "close as dupe" goof, btw), and find that sufficient. Am I being naïve to think I've sufficiently dissuaded others from engaging in the oft-observed "meta effect"? (Sigh...just writing that question, I think I know the answer. I guess the use of the word "meta" really is appropriate here...I feel like I'm falling into a whirlpool of circularity).

Comment: "viewed 1646 times" - fairly typical amount for a question stuck in hot list for about a day, not particularly high. Fake popularity; questions that are genuinely popular and get linked from solid outside places (and not just spammed inside network from sidebar) get orders of magnitude more views

Comment: @gnat: but how did it get "stuck in hot list for about a day"?

Comment: @PeterDuniho I keep an eye on the hot list and remember that question. For a less subjective assessment, [question timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32906320/timeline) provides enough data to make a solid estimate, once you get used to decipher it

Comment: @gnat: sorry, maybe I'm being dense, but I don't see anything about the question timeline that answers the question of how the question wound up on the hot list. Unless you simply mean that the large number of answers in a short period of time was in and of itself sufficient to do that?

Comment: first thing you look at is many quick answers to the question (there is a ["hotness formula"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/61343/165773) that determines how that works). Next, you pay attention to amount of upvotes to the question - 90+ in the first day, with fast decline to 26 on the next day, indicating how interest dropped when the question has left hot list. This pattern of upvotes ("flash in the pan") is typical for questions spammed through Stack Exchange sidebar. On genuinely popular questions linked from elsewhere, voting tends to be spread more evenly and doesn't decline that fast

Answer (score 13):

Just google the question title with double quotes around it and it will be obvious.  Short from the vampire sites, several of which Google ranks higher than StackExchange sites btw, you'll see hits at programmers, askubuntu, superuser, serverfault, etc.

In other words, the question was featured in the Hot Network Questions list, the one you see on the ==> right.  Short from a reddit runaway, it is the best way to win the lottery afaik.  The few times an SO question gets featured in that list, it always jacks-up the view counter to 1000+ in a few days.  Only ~1.4% of the visitors finding the question actually helpful is pretty typical too, still good enough to outscore any other active good Q+A by a factor of 4.

That a featured SO question in that list is almost never one to show off the mettle of the site is very typical as well.  It has to be one that everybody knows the answer to or has an opinion about.  You only ever win a lottery by buying a lot of tickets.

Why the C# community did not close it before it escaped is the bigger question.  Closing questions *is* hard work.  I'd assume that drowning in the 1.7 million c# substring hits probably helped.  I personally saw the question listed on my front page but never looked at it, the title was enough for me assume it wasn't interesting.  Which is the other way that questions don't get closed, the ones that look bad from a mile away are just ignored.

Comment: You know what we need? Close/downvote links from the front page. Feature request ahoy!

Comment: _"the question was featured in the Hot Network Questions list"_ -- um, okay. But how did that question wind up there? Looking [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/4789/286534), it seems a bit circular. "Hot questions" have lots of views, answers, and upvotes (on question and answers), but then saying it's a "hot question" is how it got all those views, answers and upvotes doesn't seem to explain how it got to be a hot question in the first place.

Comment: Or are you saying that by virtue of being a poor question, it was able to attract enough initial low-cost activity to give it the initial listing as a "hot question", which then pushed it even higher? If so, it seems like maybe there's something wrong with the "hot questions" feature. It doesn't seem like it should be unstable, in the sense that a small nudge can push an otherwise poor question into being highly-valued. (Compare to atmospheric instability that leads to thunderstorms)

Comment: _"Just google the question title with double quotes around it"_ -- and to be clear, I did do that exercise and did not see hits on any of the sites you mentioned. I saw only five hits for the actual question other than the main SO one, and none of those look like the sort of sites that are capable of driving much traffic, if any.

Comment: Sure.  It is entertainment, just doesn't have much to do with good Q+A for programmers.  Probably also the reason that an SO question is so rarely featured in the list, we're a pretty boring lot to the rest of the world.

Comment: Hans, compared to other sites Stack Overflow has [special adjustment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250154/165773) that strongly pushes their questions from hot list after 7 hours. I don't think boring is the reason - eg totally bland [Math.SE wish list](http://mathoverflow.net/q/213266) stuck in HNL for about a week and nobody worried. More likely, SE team can't stand amount of meta whining when SO question sticks in there for too long (remember [croissants](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190106/165773)?)

Answer (score 8):

Let me answer the more generic version of your question, "*How to find out why a recent question has accumulated so many views?*", because I often wondered about this as well. Here's a decent heuristic:

- Rely on Google. Search for the exact question title (unless the question history show it has been altered a lot), within double quotes, and add the appropriate time filter (e.g. "Past 24 hours"). If the question attracted its views from outside the SE network you'll find it this way 9 out of 10 times. In my  experience 8 out of 10 times the source is a post on **Reddit** or **Hackernews**, or **a tweet** of someone with a lot of followers.
- If the previous search gave no relevant results (e.g. first 10 results are the post itself plus some SO clones), assume the traffic was generated from inside SE. The three main sources, probably in order: **Hot Network Questions**, **Meta**, or a **chat room**.

Now, as to your other question ("How do I get this lucky?"), the answer is probably "Just Luck". I got lucky [merely asking about potatoes](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/50468/9453) with the Hot Network Questions once, and another time on Cooking.SE when being [retweeted by Jeff Atwood about fishes and dishwashers](https://twitter.com/jeroenheijmans/status/181891861546409985). Finally, relying a little less on luck, if you're willing to risk getting *negative* attention, then bringing up a question on Meta might invoke the Meta Effect and get you *some* kind of votes...

Comment: I happen to hate potatoes, fish and dishwashers...

Comment: Yikes! Guess that means meta effect downvotes incoming for me! There go my fake internetz unicorn stack exchange points of awesomeness... :'(

Comment: Okay...so, I find the above useful, but am having trouble applying it to this specific question. That is, I did the Google search and saw nothing that seemed likely to drive traffic to SO (or am I misinterpreting what I see?). If the views are coming from "Hot Network Questions", then I left puzzled by the circularity (see my comment above in response to Hans). If you're able and willing to walk me through this particular example, that would help my comprehension a lot, I think.