# Should this question get reopened?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, specific-question

Here is the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34496418/is-define-banned-in-industry-standards), in which the OP asked a question similar to 'Particular constant is banned in computer science; is this true or not?' In this case, the question was:

> I am a first year computer science student and my professor said #define
>   is banned in the industry standards along with #if, #ifdef, #else, and a few
>   other preprocessor directives. He used the word "banned" because of
>   unexpected behaviour. Is this accurate? If so why?

When I review reopen vote I get this question.

Should I reopen this type of question?
Are these types of question of good quality and can anyone ask like this type of question?

Comment: Why do you think it should be closed?

Comment: However, it was closed as **primarily opinion-based** but I don't think there's anything **primarily opinion-based**.

Comment: The question is very ho-hum (why did he not ask his professor??), it got rescued by a great answer.  Whether it gets closed or not is fairly immaterial, who is going to post a better answer?  Closing however is also considered the next stage to deletion.  Deleting Q+A that is *this* popular (5000+ views in 2 days) is not popular, surely the primary reason it got re-open votes.  If you dislike the Q+A because of the ho-hum Q then there is no reason to act on these votes.  If you like it because of the A and fear deletion then act.  It is up to you.

Comment: @KevinGuan i don't think it should be closed. i just think that is this good quality question or not?

Comment: @HansPassant I am not interested to discuss matters of quality of this question, but [I think you know](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297669/839601) that it's popularity is fake, the only reason for it is that it was [masturbated in HNQ list](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307355/how-did-this-question-get-so-many-views)

Comment: @gnat: Indeed...5000 views (now nearly 6000) and that many upvotes on a question that should never have been posted, and answers to a question that should never have been posted, can be achieved only through the artificial means that drag in a bunch of irresponsible voters. Real programming questions don't have a snowball's chance in hell of getting that many votes in a year, never mind a few days. It is depressing just how many people are willing to prop up such an inappropriate question.

Comment: @PeterDuniho you may want to read https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/01/the-trouble-with-popularity/

Comment: @Braiam: yeah, read it already. So where are the mods? Atwood's article is basically saying that in these kinds of situations, it's the moderators' job to get rid of stuff like this. The community can't do it alone.

Comment: @PeterDuniho well, moderators act in *behalf* of the community, so, in theory, if the community doesn't figure out what would be the desired state of such posts... what should they do?

Comment: @Braiam: as I wrote, they should delete the question. Moderators solve problems that the community cannot; in most cases, this means immediately deleting content that the community can't get to fast enough or can't delete at all (e.g. comments). But it would (as Atwood's article says) also apply to scenarios where the community fails their duty, e.g. due to the unfortunate effects of socially-driven behavior as Atwood describes.

Comment: @PeterDuniho then I don't understand what is your take on the matter, since the first comment to gnat's answer to Hans is my impression that you don't want the question closed and/or deleted, due the amount of votes, views *and* answers. Is my interpretation wrong?

Comment: @Braiam: yes, that's not what I meant. Hans correctly observes deleting the question may be difficult due to the traffic, gnat correctly observes that popular though the question may be, it's not _fairly_ popular. I am simply affirming gnat's observation and pointing out that the level of "popularity" for the question is unprecedented for any "real" question on SO. As I wrote, I find the situation "depressing".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

On the surface, the question appears valid, but there has been no attempt to research the issue and is likely to waste a lot of members' time, when the OP could have found out the result very quickly. A look inside any of the standard headers included with his compiler would have informed him that this is not true.

This also suggests that the OP is not even aware of such golden rules as "no magic numbers", indicating that OP should be spending some additional time reading and learning to write software before starting to ask questions.

It's a matter of just how basic Stack Overflow wants to become. I believe this site is not *Programming for dummies* and the question should remain closed.

Finally, there is the issue of coding guidelines being (to a degree) subjective. This question is not much different to a question about capitalization or indentation.

Comment: *Finally, there is the issue of coding guidelines being (to a degree) subjective* - yeah, to a **high** degree. Its pretty much an involuntary firestarter question that can draw out the people looking to make their own opinion a fact. The sheer number of answers that go all directions on the linked question pretty much back that up :) Its mostly "HELL NO!" answers, and then along comes the interesting "why yes certainly" answer, which can actually back itself up with sources: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34518280/424903

Comment: Often things allowed for frameworks and standard libraries are not welcome in production code, so that's not the way. And why are you talking about magic numbers?

Comment: A lack of understanding and / or shown research is **never** a reason to close a question. The question in question could be closed for other reasons, but never because it doesn't show research effort or a minimal understanding. Those are only reasons to downvote.

Comment: I'm not convinced a newcomer to C could find the references very quickly.  It took me a while to come up with a list of examples — and I didn't have an example that supported the contention of the OP's professor (someone else did).

Comment: Does anyone think i should modify this answer to reflect the collective opinions, rather than just my own?

Comment: @MarkCh no, you should keep your (accepted) answer your own. If any of us have something different to say or something to add, we should get off our butts and add an answer ourselves :)

Answer (score 9):

This is not the only question I have seen, the short answer on which is

> No. First I've heard of it.

The last time I saw such a question I downvoted it instead of close voting: While the question is on-topic and have a single answer, it obviously lack research. At that time I expected the question could be massively downvoted (so being closed by the author or by the system), but now I see that expectation was false.

Now I think that almost *any* of non-off-topic reasons could be a reason for close voting:

### Too broad:

There are a lot of documents (standards, specifications, etc.) concerning the C language, ones are widely-used, and others are domain-specific. **Should we enumerate all of them** which doesn't ban `#define`?

Phrase `industry standards`, used in the question, doesn't reduce this list of documents to a reasonable amount.

### Primary opinion-based:

Question can be read as

> Why could my professor say that?

Obviously opinion-based.

### Unclear what you are asking:

Even this close voting reason could be used, but the ones above are preferrable.