# Rate of new votes declining on Stack Overflow posts

Tags: discussion, voting

Fewer and fewer people are voting on Stack Overflow posts. Check these queries:

**Votes** - https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1303081/votes-on-posts-year-on-year

> [image]

**Posts** - https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1303527/cumulative-posts-all-years

> [image]

As is evident, only 21 million votes were cast in 2019 as against 23 million in 2017. Moreover, the 21 M votes *includes posts before 2019 as well.* Which means the votes/available posts ratio is declining at an even faster pace.

```
votes/post | year
------------------
23 M /33 M | 2016
21 M /47 M | 2019
```

Considering that cumulative posts by 2019 are about 47 million, the votes should have also followed the similar upsurge. I understand 2020 still has three more months to go.

***Why are people casting fewer votes?*** Is this due to fewer new active users?

Comment: why are you cross-posting?

Comment: Since I specifically analysed stackoverflow, not other stackexchange sites.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316216/how-does-stack-overflow-prevent-the-panda-algorithm-penalty

Comment: Well I don't make it a habit to go to Stack Overflow just to vote, there is simply too much to vote on so it would be incredibly tiring and time consuming. Thus I only vote in those moments where I interact with the site. When I'm looking for something to answer in a free moment, when I'm searching for an answer to a question/problem I'm having or when I'm reviewing. That's not a whole lot of time in total.

Comment: Generally, we are putting more votes on the recent posts than on the elder ones. In my understanding, the ratio "recent votes/cumulative posts" is not a very good figure of merit.

Comment: Does the query you are using actually back your claims? It doesn't appear to do so.

Comment: Not fewer new active users, but fewer new good-quality/mind-blowing posts.

Comment: Speaking from my own posts, it feels like almost all votes come in within a few days after posting, and only very, very few come in on old posts. Thus, I do not think votes/cumulative posts is a meaningful metric. Furthermore, 2020 isn't over yet, and we had monica-gate which saw many highly active users reduce participation - which includes voting.

Comment: @Damien please explain "the ratio recent votes/cumulative posts is not a very good figure of merit." 23 Million votes in 2016 were casted on all 33 Million posts available till that year. "recent votes/cumulative posts" should have remained more or less constant. But this ratio is steadily declining.

Comment: @jerrymouse Even if the number of posts per year is unchanged, the ratio posts this year over all posts is decreasing. As we don't vote so much on old posts, then the ratio "votes this year" over "all posts" is mechanically decreasing. A better criteria, far from being perfect, should be the ratio "votes on this year posts" over "posts this year". That being said, looking at your figures, I agree that a decrease should be observed, whatever the criteria.

Comment: you should measure number of visits per year (probably fewer in 2019 than 2016)

Comment: "recent votes/cumulative posts should have remained more or less constant". If there are 10 million votes to go around, and the # of users stay constant and thus the # of votes, then the # of votes on cumulative posts will steadily decrease because the pool of old posts is constantly growing, while the # of votes is not.

Comment: It would be interesting to see a percentage of users who have enough reputation to vote, and see if there's a correlation.

Comment: Personally, I'm less voting as before since SO has decided to give 10 points to upvoted questions.

Comment: Also (and the confusion it creates is apparent in some comments and one of the answers) - the query does not distinguish between upvotes, downvotes, moderation votes ( closure, reopen, offensive, spam, etc ). It would be more meaningful a metric if split into categories. Btw, there is a `PostsWithDeleted` table to look into for when considering the overall trend.

Comment: Maybe voting is only for new users. Those that benefit from the instant pop-up (not tool-tip) and those that cannot remember what the buttons means. For others the pop-up is insulting, and some of us just avoid it as much as possible. To be honest, I'm not convinced that Stack wants us to vote. I hear a lot of talk that more voting is needed, but I can't remember ever having heard it from Stack.

Comment: @Scratte: What does the pop-up say?

Answer (score 31):

This took a while, but I went with your original query and started to put together a query that gives a far more comprehensive overview over the situation:

[SEDE: Votes over the Years](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1303929/votes-per-post-over-the-years)

```
Year Posts (Year) Posts (All) Votes (Current) Votes (Old) Votes (Year) Votes / Post (Current) Votes / Post (Old) 
---- ------------ ----------- --------------- ----------- ------------ ---------------------- ------------------ 
2008 0.27 M       0.27 M      0.60 M          0.00 M      0.60 M       2.21                   0                  
2009 1.28 M       1.55 M      2.50 M          0.30 M      2.80 M       1.95                   1.12               
2010 2.16 M       3.71 M      3.68 M          0.94 M      4.63 M       1.71                   0.61               
2011 3.48 M       7.18 M      5.63 M          2.40 M      8.03 M       1.62                   0.65               
2012 4.48 M       11.66 M     7.19 M          5.10 M      12.29 M      1.6                    0.71               
2013 5.39 M       17.05 M     7.98 M          8.26 M      16.25 M      1.48                   0.71               
2014 5.37 M       22.42 M     7.06 M          9.80 M      16.86 M      1.31                   0.57               
2015 5.37 M       27.79 M     7.49 M          11.73 M     19.21 M      1.39                   0.52               
2016 5.30 M       33.09 M     7.15 M          13.28 M     20.43 M      1.35                   0.48               
2017 5.05 M       38.14 M     6.52 M          13.80 M     20.32 M      1.29                   0.42               
2018 4.47 M       42.61 M     5.88 M          13.66 M     19.53 M      1.31                   0.36               
2019 4.29 M       46.90 M     5.28 M          13.68 M     18.96 M      1.23                   0.32               
2020 3.66 M       50.56 M     3.77 M          10.54 M     14.31 M      1.03                   0.22               

(13 row(s) returned)
```

As for 2020s count, we have to remember that we are only on day #275 of the year. Assuming the rate stays the same, we can thus expect (366/275) * 16.05M ~= 21.36M votes this year and (366/275) * 3.66M ~= 4.87M posts this year (that would be an uptick, but I don't know the seasonal variations in the post rate, the christmas season might very well lull the post count).

- **2013** was the first year when more votes were left on old then on new questions.
- Posts are declining since 2013 (slowly till 2016, then more rapidly)
- Total votes peaked in 2016
- Votes on current posts peaked in 2013 with 7.98 M
- Votes per Posts on current posts are declining ever since SO began until 2014. Since then it has bounced around 1.31 and has now dropped to 1.03
- Votes/Post on old posts are also declining.

This isn't an answer to the why, but it gives a bit more food for thought for later answers.

Comment: It would be nice to know split of up/down votes too.

Comment: @Dharman Feel free to fork the query and work from there. As you can see, its already quite a beast (and takes ages to run), so I'm not digging any further at the moment. Furthermore, votes are an indicator of activity (how healthy is our curation?). Its not really all that interesting if up or down.

Comment: Neat analysis you have there!

Comment: interesting to match this with the timing of [decline in development of features](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314348/165773) addressing the needs of site core group (ie of users who probably vote most). There was a sharp drop in 2015, followed by a further decline in next three years

Comment: What about count od new users post year.

Comment: Votes per post is misleading, since posts can get deleted over time, specifically, year-old posts with no votes nor activity get roomba'ed. This means that for 2019 and 2020, numbers are really inaccurate, for years before that, only slightly since deletions beyond that are often more rare.

Comment: @ErikA If you have a good idea how to compensate that which doesn't blow this already large query completely out of proportion, feel free to add some pointers. Otherwise, it is what it is.

Comment: @Polygnome for accurate posts counts, you can just swap `Posts` for `PostsWithDeleted`. The hard part is getting vote counts for deleted posts, which you could try to infer by looking at the score and upvote/downvote ratio for that score, but unfortunately that's both difficult and still biased (that ratio might be different for deleted posts). I just wanted to caution against overinterpreting the results, especially regarding the last two years, not say the query should be improved

Comment: @ErikA No worries, I absolutely get your point, but as you said, its not that easy to find ways around it. Still, those values should have somewhat stabilized for the older years, and the trend is visible ever since the start of SO. Maybe I'll revisit this tomorrow, I  have one or two ideas for score based inference.