# Sudden increase in the number of votes: bug or suspicious activity?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I was just editing my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49560505/use-the-right-color-scale-for-data-skewed-to-right) when, out of the blue, an impossible amount of upvotes appeared in the question and all its answers suddenly.

At the time I started my edit the question had just 1 upvote (which was mine, you can see my comment complaining about the lack of upvotes), one of the answers had 2 upvotes and the other two answers (one of them being mine) had 1 upvote.

Then, when I saved my edit (a couple of minutes later) I saw `50` in the achievements, instantly. When I checked what could be that I saw that the upvotes came from the answer I just edited: the question has now 10 upvotes, and the answers have now 4, 7 and 5 upvotes respectively. That seems to be impossible.

Here is the screenshot (with the compulsory red freehand) in case the system fixes the bug (or revert the votes if this is a voting ring):

[image]

PS: as an additional information, at the same time the upvotes appeared one of the answers was accepted. It was not accepted 2 minutes before.

Comment: What makes you so sure it's a _bug_? It could be someone telling their friends: Look at this question, that's just what we need!

Comment: @Cerbrus It's seems impossible. I took no more than a couple of minutes editing my answer, and when I saved it, bum! Ten upvotes in the question and 4 (because I already had 1) upvotes in my answer! Also, on top of that, I believe that I saw 33 or 34 as the number of views when it had 1 upvote only, and the question right now (at the time of writing) has only 38 views!

Comment: View count has always been unreliable. How long did the update take?

Comment: @Cerbrus Do you mean the time I took to edit my answer? a couple of minutes. Have in mind that [tag:d3.js] is a very small popularity tag. If that is not a bug it is, at least, a very suspicious activity!

Comment: I think a voting ring would not upvote all answers + the question.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yet, this is strange: if you look at the timestamps (see BoltClock answer below) all the votes and the accepted answer occurred in less than 2 and a half minutes.

Comment: okay maybe a _smart_ voting ring then.

Comment: it's certainly not impossible to get a large number of upvotes in a short period of time.

Comment: Oh, the meta effect: now that the linked question is getting attention it already has 3 close votes as *opinion-based*. That question is **not** opinion based. The fact that OP asked *"What is the right color scale to use?"* doesn't make it opinion-based: there is indeed a right scale to use according to the data visualization principles and the desired outcome.

Comment: One year on I notice some (many?) of those upvotes are gone (the question is now +9/-5 and your answer +2/-1) so perhaps it was a voting ring and the users have since been deleted.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Not a bug. The question did in fact gain an upvote once nearly every 10 seconds or less while you were editing your answer. The [corresponding reputation changes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3425699/katherine-maurus?tab=reputation&sort=post) on the asker's profile show this.

If this is extremely unusual for a [d3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/d3.js) question, we'll keep an eye out. But the fact that you yourself were earlier lamenting how the question wasn't getting any upvotes despite ticking all the boxes *might* have motivated some of the votes.

Comment: Can you see if it had been on the hot question list? Because that could explain votes as well. It might not need a long time on it.

Comment: @rene: No, I can't see that data. If I were to guess, the question has only had 47 views in 16 hours, so I doubt it's been on hot questions.

Comment: Well, so that's definitely suspicious. @rene even if it was in the hotlist (and I doubt it), that doesn't explain 10 upvotes in a couple of minutes. I mean, not for such a question. On top of that, the upvotes simply stopped after 2 minutes.

Comment: @BoltClock since this seems to be a suspicious activity (vote ring?) instead of a bug, should I edit my question's title? Or delete it altogether?

Comment: @Gerardo Furtado: You can edit the title if you want and I'll revert the tags to [discussion].

Comment: Fair enough, I always like to stay of the *assume good faith* path until all  options are exhausted....

Comment: @rene: For comparison, [this question I answered a couple of days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49528774/does-jquerys-html-method-auto-join-the-argument-if-its-an-array) entered hot questions and received 100 views in 24 hours and the first 5 upvotes in 7 minutes.

Comment: Your shiny diamond attract votes ;) ... Okay, I got it.

Comment: @rene you can use [Passant's trick](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307361/839601) to find out whether some question was in HNQ

Comment: @gnat: Yep, I have also used that to good effect.

Comment: It is very suspicious indeed. I'm prompted to say it's highly unlikely that could really happen without any fraud involved.

Comment: That sudden voting occurs *15 hours* since the question was asked.