# Should a bad question by a newbie spared from being downvoted?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, low-quality-posts, new-users

There was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51870415/how-do-i-customize-the-action-of-the-submit-button-to-run-controllers-function/51870619?noredirect=1#51870415) i came across.

(It has been edited since, so here is the screenshot of its first revision.)

[image]

I found this question to be of low quality as it was lacking a lot of aspects e.g. What has OP tried to make it work?, What code he is using?, What (if any) error he is facing?, to sum it up, What is stopping OP from doing it?

So, I went ahead and downvoted the question. The reason for my downvote had *already* been posted as comments by other users asking OP to improve the question. So, I restrained from adding a duplicate comment.

In a discussion on an answer to this question, I got the feedback from another user:

> That's your choice but I don't agree with your downvote because the person has a rep of 1. So downvoting in this instance is discouraging. I believe if someone has a higher rep then bad questions should be downvoted. This is clearly a newbie.

To me, a bad question is a bad question. It has nothing to do with the rep of OP. Am I wrong in believing that? Is there any *special* criteria for downvoting questions of new users?

Comment: If we look at the user's rep to vote.. The net vote will not reflect the quality of the post would it?

Comment: The user had already been told how to improve the question. The kind thing to do, if you have some time to spare, is go back later and see if they have improved the question.

Comment: @S.L.Barth Does anyone actually go back to see if the question was improved? (*legitimate question*)

Comment: @IvankaTodorova I sometimes do. On a few occassions, the user actually did take comments to heart, and added more information.

Comment: @IvankaTodorova I too go back to the questions if I see a comment from OP that he has edited the question. That's why I was open to retract the vote if (and when) OP improves the question description.

Comment: How do you keep track of those questions. Sometimes I comment on them (if I can add something valuable) and go to the `all actions` tab in my profile, but other times I cannot think of anything else to say and I "lose" them.

Comment: That comment is fairly backwards, a user cannot lose any rep from a downvote when he never earned any.  Most important aspect is that comments *need to be on topic*.  Berating users for how they use their vote has nothing whatsoever to do with the question of course.  So be sure to flag the comment as "no longer needed".  If you are going to post a comment yourself then do make sure it assists the user in improving his question.  As-is that looks to be almost impossible to me, so you probably shouldn't comment at all.

Comment: 'This is clearly a newbie'.. or another sock puppet, ring-voting member, ban-evasion or one-Q-per-week burner account.   I don't care - if it's not new/usefulresearched, downvote it.

Comment: see also: [Is downvoting new users a barrier to Stack Overflow's growth?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/296037/839601)

Comment: Good find @gnat. That was exactly it.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

No, never.

Vote based on the post's merits.
What kind of user is attached to the post is completely irrelevant.

If a new user posts a *bad* question, and doesn't get downvoted, they won't learn that bad questions aren't welcome.

Comment: see also: [Disable downvoting for users with reputation less than 50](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272269/839601), "Don't handicap your children by making their lives easy..."