# Let's reframe voting

Tags: discussion, feature-request

> You've got to accentuate the positive
>   Eliminate the negative
>   Latch on to the affirmative
>   Don't mess with Mister In-Between

**Questions:** No downvoting.

It's a scale shift with brain candy: don't highlight how "awful" something is–just leave it be.

**Question Feedback:**

Provide an official mechanism for partialy-automated question feedback.

While many of us are running macros/expanders to provide friendly, measured feedback, why not just have some UX to plug that stuff in, SE-wide, with useful and relevant links, instead of relying on a hodgepodge of ad-hoc solutions or idownvotedbecause etc.?

**Answers:** A mechanisms to indicate accuracy/correctness/suitability is required.

Couch votes in different language like works/doesn't work or agree/disagree.

Some mechanism for weighting voter input could also be put into place, e.g., "I'm an expert on this, and this answer is the best" etc. Clearly there is handwaving here, but with the amount of data we have about our answerers, it seems like at least a step in this direction could be taken.

**Pie in the Sky:** Proportional voting.

A wall of roughly-equal-vote answers doesn't mean they're equivalent. While it'd require more discipline, it would also surface most-agreed-upon solutions, especially when votes are close.

*Edit* The "dupe" addresses only the downvote feedback question. This question/conversation calls for the elimination or modification of downvoting altogether.

Comment: _No downvoting_ So everything can only be neutral or positive? Life just ain't like that my friend, song or no song :/

Comment: I appreciate that fact you're trying to offer ways to improve, but when you write "*just leave it be*," it makes me wonder if you've seen the horrors inside the Triage or VLQ queue recently.  Some things can't just be left as they are (fix, edit, remove, whatever, but not "meh").

Comment: **"It's a scale shift with brain candy: don't highlight how "awful" something is–just  leave it be."** .. this has been asked/request before and wasn't that successful at that. Why do you expect a different result now? **"why not just have some UX to plug that stuff in, SE-wide, with useful and relevant links"** The position of SE/SO Inc is that they don't like copy/paste text written under many questions containing links to a lot of information which may or may not apply to the post at hand. They see that as unwelcoming, so I don't think you'll get that feature implemented.

Comment: While we're at it, lets replace upvoting with hearts. SO will become the new twitter.

Comment: Most definitely show how awful a bad question / answer is - that is the entire purpose of a Q&A site - to surface good questions and good answers and to bury bad ones so that visitors can find reliable information on the topic they research. Neutering downvotes would deny visitors this possibility by making posters of bad questions / answers feel good about themselves.

Comment: @Tom The point is *explicitly* to provide relevant links. Hell, we can't even link to relevant sections in the help pages.

Comment: 1. (_no downvote_) Do you mean to reduce differentiation between good and bad answers? Bad imho, there already is too much LQ content not standing out as such.  2. (_accuracy rating_) Good idea. However, I regularly see claims (pro and con) about some solution which are but a consequence of flawed adoption of the answer, shouldn't one guard against these ? 3. (_weighting input_) Excellent idea. 4. (_Proportional voting_) Nice to have but probably not worth the trouble (no intuitive rules on proportionality scales) and prone to abuse.

Comment: @collapsar Yea, proportional voting would be fraught and likely not worth the effort.

Comment: **"The point is explicitly to provide relevant links."** that wasn't so successful for all those existing idownvotedbecau.se sub-pages, so how should SO Inc. tackle that? Provide even more pre-written texts to be less generic? **"Hell, we can't even link to relevant sections in the help pages"** I agree there, some anchors in those help pages were useful.

Comment: @Tom There are a few often-used responses to poor questions; I cannot think of any reason those, at least, couldn't be codified/normalized.

Comment: I *just* came here after seeing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58454543/i-want-e-mail-bar-for-my-website-please-use-only-html-css-js). For the record, the *entirety* of the question is "*I want a bar on my website. For e-mail. Please use only HTML, CSS and JS. And I want the email to be written to domain.xyz/subs.txt*". I very heartily disagree that it shouldn't be downvoted.

Comment: @VLAZ A downvote alone is pointless and does nothing to improve the situation. It's not how I treat my kids--ignorance should be met with education, not being hit with a bat. Your response to that question is valid and correct--but insufficient.

Comment: The problem with requiring a link to elsewhere is the presumption that the feedback will actually be read.  We're already shovelling introductions and familiarization text in front of new users, where they have to acknowledge they've read it.  Spoiler: they didn't.  They're not going to read these links, either.  The ones that would, already try to familiarize themselves.  The drive to improve has to come from within, not beaten into them with a bat.

Comment: @fbueckert *shrug* I have a different view of humanity than you do. Yes, people that genuinely don't want to learn won't, and they'll stop asking questions because SO will be useless to them. Not providing resources for those that *do* is counter-productive.

Comment: A down-vote is fine if you know what it means. SE needs to invest time and effort into teaching folks that a down-vote means bad content and not people piling on the OP. Removing the down-vote option won't solve anything.

Comment: The resources *are* provided.  Granted, we can make it easier to find, but at no point are they not there.  You're perpetuating the age-old myth that downvotes are hostile, and don't see the very real value they provide.  Downvoting is, by far, one of the most important things you can do.  They likely save future readers far more time than upvoting ever would.

Comment: @Script47 This is somewhat true, somewhat not: I'd just rather have easy means of providing the education without the simultaneous punishment.

Comment: @DaveNewton we have a tour and the help docs. If you can't be bothered looking through them then you shouldn't complain if you receive a bad reception (down-votes and close-votes).

Comment: @Script47 Voting to close and downvotes present very differently--at least close votes are accompanied by a (limited set) of canned reasons.

Comment: A lot of people abhor SO precisely because it's perceived as unwelcoming. Haughty comments do nothing to resolve that (and out of the people commenting on this thread I'd wager I'm *far* more guilty of that than any of you). If less dickish options are provided as easy defaults IMO it's less likely to be a problem.

Comment: @DaveNewton the reason I mentioned close-votes was because people tend to lump it in with down-votes but either way, my point still stands.

Comment: @Script47 Your point is (roughly) that nobody can be rehabilitated. I simply cannot agree.

Comment: @DaveNewton I don't know how you got that from my point. My point is that those who don't want to be helped (don't want to look at the tour or the help pages) can't be helped.

Comment: @Script47 I'm saying that most people *can* be helped, it just takes encouragement. Many SO users don't even *try* to help; having a standard mechanism to *encourages* help beyond pithy comments would be a net benefit. You're saying "hey, they screwed up, they can't be helped." That's a pretty blighted view of things; hopefully you're not a teacher. Adults aren't children--but that doesn't mean that they don't need encouragement too. Driving people away doesn't benefit SO, and it certainly doesn't benefit the asker.

Comment: @DaveNewton nope, once again, that's not what I'm saying. You talk about being helpful yet you throw veiled insults at me ('*hopefully you're not a teacher*') while misconstruing what I say. At no point do I suggest they don't need help. At no point do I suggest they don't need encouragement. I do however, unequivocally, say that reworking the down-vote to prevent people from down-voting bad content will not help. As for your last point, pushing away bad content from SO will *definitely* help SO.

Comment: Fundamentally, I believe you misunderstand what SO is (even with your high rep, BTW, this isn't intended as an insult, more of an observation), we're not here to mentor people, we're about collecting quality Q&A and by definition it will exclude some types of content. If as a side result people are mentored then hey,  that's a good thing. But let's not make that our focus at the expense of quality.

Comment: I think if you scope down proposal to just answer it will be much easier sell  - even now only most outragedly wrong answers are downvoted, so removal of downvotes would be pretty minor... Policy on questions so can only be decided after we (if ever) get guidance what is currently desired type of questions... So voted as "not useful" on this proposal rather than agreeing or disagreeing with it.

Comment: @Script47 I believe that's a short-sighted approach. I've said nothing about lowering the quality bar--it's about *raising* the quality bar and *educating* (different than mentoring), but doing so in a way that doesn't come across as an attack--which it very often does.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov You are likely correct.

Comment: @DaveNewton on "educating" - so far you have not suggested anything that will not be interpreted as attack. I don't see how "doesn't work" can be considered non-offensive... or how "I'm an expert on this, and this answer is the best" is not "this @#$@# elitist does not see my answer as the bestest evar - you all suck"...

Comment: @DaveNewton right so rather than trying to rework the voting, you'd be much better off teaching new users that down-votes are not attacks against them. Either way, I believe we're at an impasse so we'll agree to disagree (which again, is fine too).

Comment: @Script47 I will update my personal automation process to include said verbiage; that's a good idea. Why people would be resistant to providing a normalized, SE-wide approach to doing so is quite beyond me.

Comment: Charter for homework cheats and selfish abusers, V9,7

Answer (score 18):

Downvotes are *important*.  Even discounting the systems tied to them (question bans, rate limits, etc.), downvoting is arguably one of the most important things users can do.

We can't make posters read. We can't make them post content that meet our standards.  What we *can* do is ensure that future readers know that the post has problems.  *That* is one of the very reasons SO exists; to save future readers the pain of sifting the chaff from the wheat, increase the signal to noise ratio.

Bad content is *noise*.  Removing downvotes does nothing to further that goal; all it does is make it harder for future readers to figure out what's good and what isn't.  And before you argue that zero scored posts do that, no, it doesn't.  It *can* mean that, but it can just as easily mean nobody has seen it.  There's no way to tell.  On the scale of SO, there's not *nearly* enough people to sift through all the new posts and try to curate them.  There's even *less* time to actually constructively provide feedback to all of them to help the poster.

Downvotes are not for the poster.  They need to have the drive to put in effort themselves to improve.  We can't instill that.  Downvotes are for the future readers, so that *their* time is spent as productively as possible.

Comment: This essentially reiterates your viewpoint that askers cannot be reformed, so the best thing we can do is hope that future askers see those bad questions and know what to do (and not to do). My viewpoint is that most askers *can* be reformed (and I've seen it happen), and that providing tools to aid in that reformation is net positive.

Comment: Personal responsibility is exactly that.  The tools are there; they're just required to pick them up themselves.  We're not here to help the asker; that's never been the goal.  Making it so only destroys the site as we know it.  It's not about reformation; it's about looking beyond the poster to who *else* can be helped by the post.

Comment: @DaveNewton To add to this answer (which I think is good) - bad content is not _just_ noise - it could be misleading to someone who doesn't know better. Bad content is poison and downvotes serve as an indicator to _others_ of this agreement of the community. This has nothing to do with reforming anyone - after posting a downvoted question, the poster is not forbidden from posting better ones.

Comment: @fbueckert I'm saying we *should* help the asker: that extends beyond the merely technical. I don't see anything wrong with trying to help someone as a person as well as answering technical questions. In fact I think it's *important* that SO helps produce better *developers*, which extends beyond just being able to make something work.

Comment: @xxbbcc IMO you're contradicting yourself. Indicating a question is bad without providing reasonable, reasoned feedback regarding *why* it's bad isn't educational.

Comment: I'm saying there's too many askers to help them.  It's a losing proposition to try; you're just going to burn yourself out in the process.  Posters are required to meet our standards, and *not* meeting them is feedback that *has* to be provided.  [We're trying to build a castle out of cabinets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/378863/), not a blanket fort.  One lasts for the day, the other for centuries.  It takes more exacting engineering to build for the long term, and that's what we're doing.

Comment: @fbueckert That may be the *goal*, but it's not what's happening on the ground. Some people actively dislike SO's "personality"--and SO's attempts to dispel this have failed so far. I'm saying lower the bar to providing help precisely so people *don't* get burned out. Because I've automated some of that help, I *don't* get burned out trying to be educational while being (generally) friendly. (With the caveat that I've been closer to the ban-hammer than most people commenting on this question precisely because I lose patience with the learning-resistent.)

Comment: @DaveNewton I used to add comments to questions when I downvoted them but I stopped when I got serial downvoted or yelled at. It didn't happen many times but I don't think I'm obligated to help out scum so now I just downvote. You're right, it's not very educational but there are some people that can't be helped. It's a sad fact.

Comment: @xxbbcc Agreed, some people can't. Most people can. I find it unlikely that reasonable comments brought about yelling (and serial downvoting is almost always caught by the system anyway).

Comment: @DaveNewton You're right, the serials were reversed (to some extent). In my experience on SO, people who are willing to improve actually go and read the help pages after being downvoted and try to improve or they ask for advice on Meta. I'd be happy to provide anonymous downvote reasons if they were available but downvotes are less for the poster and more for future visitors. Removing downvotes would defeat the purpose of the sites.

Comment: @DaveNewton People actively disliking SO's personality because we enforce standards is something I am eminently willing to live with.  We have a bar.  People have to meet that bar.  *shrug*  Not our job to make it lower because there's more people that can't meet it than can.  I'm not willing to have to spend more effort on people than they're willing to spend on themselves.

Comment: @fbueckert That is not what engenders the dislike. The dislike comes from *how* standards are enforced. Standards can be enforced without being dickish, which is what it often ends up as.

Comment: Downvotes are not, "dickish".  They're not hostile.  They're not toxic.  They are *curation*.  How, pray tell, should we be enforcing standards that doesn't hit one of the endless suggestions to add comments to downvotes?  I've established that downvotes are required, so you can't just throw out the primary curation tool, either.  Both of those are dead horses.

Comment: At the end of the day, I believe everyone has a responsibility to own their actions.  That is sometimes an unpleasant feeling, but necessary to grow and learn.  Trying to eliminate feedback so that people don't feel bad does them a massive disservice.  [Don't handicap your children by making their lives easy.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272256/disable-downvoting-for-users-with-reputation-less-than-50/272269#272269)

Comment: @fbueckert And I didn’t say downvotes were dickish—but downvotes are not the only feedback people give. People dislike SO because of the comments, rudeness, and hostility. You keep saying I’m asking for the elimination of feedback, which hasn’t come up *anywhere*. I’m saying make feedback *educational*, which you believe is a bad idea. That’s fine, but small-minded and short-sighted.

Comment: I wonder what would happen if I described  the LGBT+ demographics as hostile, toxic, dickish etc?  I would probably be suspended forever.  It seems that the CoC only protects some groups and that flaying curators is just fine.  Inclusivity?  Bah, humbug...

Comment: @DaveNewton Feedback is meant for the post, not the poster.  Education is not, and *should not*, be a requirement.  We treat everyone as an adult here; they're expected to be responsible for their own actions.  They don't get a pass because they decided they don't have to read or follow the rules.  The focus on the user you have isn't the focus we have.  I don't think it's small minded, but thanks for the backhanded insult?

Comment: @DaveNewton I, and no doubt many others, would be only too happy to look up and regurgitate rules, policy, 'Computers 101' knowledge etc.  The only issue I see is that SO has no mechanism for paying for researchers and elementary level teachers to assist with one-on-one training.  A skilled and experienced developer would want ~$50/hr for their time.

Comment: @fbueckert I have no sympathy for people that let the ignorant remain so. Do I think some people are irredeemable? Sure—but I also give the benefit of the doubt (within reason). A downvote isn’t educational: pointing to reasons and/or enumerating them is. If there’s no education beyond downvotes, regardless of whose responsibility it is, it’s unlikely meaningful change will be effected.

Comment: @MartinJames SO doesn’t pay for answering questions, either, so that "defense" falls flat before even leaving the ground.

Comment: The point of downvotes has *never* been to educate.  I don't know how often I need to say that.  It's not supposed to educate.  It's supposed to denote a user's judgement of the value of the post.  That's it, that's all.  We tie it into other systems to help ensure that feedback gets recognized, but that's what it's for.  Not to tell someone they have to improve.  Not to salve some indignation that users don't have to paint a target on their backs to justify that judgement.  Education is not, and has never been, the goal.

Comment: Consider that we already don't get enough curation to deal with the flood of poorly thought out questions SO gets. Anything that makes curation take more effort - like say mandatory downvote explanation - won't get more people educated. It'll result in people doing less curation.

Comment: @DaveNewton I can answer questions, or not.  Nobody is trying to force me to spend powers-of-10 more time on something than that required for a downvote click.  You are suggesting a mandatory control over volunteered effort.  You want 'someone else' to do the grunt work of reading rules etc.  No defense is needed against such a suggestion, since it is plainly bad.

Comment: @MartinJames If there was an icon representing, say, the five most common "bad question" responses you couldn't be bothered to click one? Note that nowhere in my suggestions did I make feedback mandatory (even though I think it should be--it's too easy to not be helpful). Maybe you're responding to a different post.